# How to change column name while joining the query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to change the column name while joining the MySQL query. I am explaining my code below.

```
select * from grc_action left join grc_users on grc_action.action_owner=grc_users.user_id
```

I am giving my table below.

> grc_action:

```
id    name    action_owner
```

> grc_users:

```
user_id   name
```

The above is my table structure and as both has same column name `i.e-name` here I need to change the  `grc_users` table column `i.e-name` while fetching the record. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AS`

```
SELECT table1.name AS exampleName, table2.name AS otherName FROM sometable
```

You can also use this on tables:

```
SELECT vltn.id, vltn.name FROM veryLongTableName AS vltn
```

---

You dont need to type the `AS`, you can just do `SELECT table1.name exampleName` to shorten it, but it increases readbility and maintanability to write it, so I recommend doing it with `AS`.

Answer (score 0):

You may assign different aliases to the `name` columns from the two different tables.

```
select
    ga.id,
    ga.name as action_name,
    ga.action_owner,
    gu.user_id,
    gu.name as user_name
from grc_action ga
left join grc_users gu
    on ga.action_owner = gu.user_id;
```

Note that I also used table aliases which make the query easier to read.  In general, doing `SELECT *` is undesirable, and it is usually better to explicitly list the columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from grc_action 
left join grc_users on grc_action.action_owner=grc_users.user_id
```

changed query  use this query

```
select *,grc_users.name as grcuser_name,grc_action.name as grcaction_name 
from grc_action 
left join grc_users on grc_action.action_owner=grc_users.user_id
```

Here  geting two name like this
grcuser_name ,
grcaction_name

Comment: Hi. The anser you've given has already been given. On SO we like unique answers, so if have nothing to add, it's suggested not to answer. If you feel like you have actually something new to add, do feel free to post it. Otherwise, it's recommended to not post (or in this case delete it).

Comment: You can use codeformat in your answer to improve readability. I've done it in this answer, I suggest you read the edit to see what I did (the 4 spaces in front of a line).